# Create running length index

Tags: r, dplyr

Consider this data frame:

```
DT <- data.frame(id = rep(1:3, each = 5),
                 seq = c(1,3,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,1,1,1,1)
```

What I want to do is create a column called `nth_instance` which should look like this:

```
DT <- data.frame(id = rep(1:3, each = 5),
                 seq = c(1,3,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,1,1,1,1),
                 nth_instance = c(1,2,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,5,1,1,1,1,1))
```

Create a column that counts the distinct occurrences of `seq` column but also in a running length fashion. It would be nice if it is a `dplyr` solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need data.table.

```
DT %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(nth_instance = rleid(seq))
```

Comment: You can as well mark the answer as correct!